# AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, python-requests

I got this error

> AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'open'

when tried running the script below :

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('key', 'mykeyhere'),
)

data = open('request.json')
response = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you share the entire traceback? you error is not related but I'm curious. Actually it may be related, but you also have other buggy-stuff.

Comment: That code does not produce that error.  Does your actual code perhaps say `requests.open` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Python function [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
returns a file object, while the `data` parameter in requests.post is expecting a dictionary, or at least something other than a file object. The endpoint will be expecting a JSON-encoded object, but I don't think the error you'd see for sending text would show up as a Python AttributeError.
You could try something like `data=data.read()` and see if that resolves your issue.

...but that's not related to the error you mention, so I might be missing some information.

Answer (score 0):

I got error because I  named the file requests.py. After changing the filename, there is no more error.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('key', 'mykeyhere'),
)

with open('request.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file) # Now you have proper json instead of an io object 

response = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
```